# Rails belongs_to and has_many of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I am trying to create a database schema in rails between two models **Users** and **Circles**. A circle is a user defined group known only to the user who created this. The Circle contains other users that the user selected to be in that circle and a circle name.

So my solution is the following:

1. Users model: **has_many: Circles**
2. Circles model: **belongs_to: User**, **has_many: Users**

I know that there exists a **has_many through** method but I don't know if that's necessary for my case.

Comment: It's not unless you want to access Users directly from User, which doesn't sound like you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need two different associations. The first is a one-to-many association. The lazy way to set it up would be:

```
class Circle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :circles
end
```

This links users to circles through the foreign key column `user_id` on circles. Buts its pretty ambigous - what does user.circles mean? Is it circles a user has created or those he is a member of? Better be a bit more explicit even if it takes some configuration:

```
class RenameUserToCreator < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    rename_column :circles, :user_id, :creator_id
  end
end

# rails g model circle 
class Circle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_circles, 
    class_name: 'Circle',
    foreign_key: :creator_id
end
```

Next you want to add members to a circle. This is a many-to-many association and can be done using `has_many through:` or `has_or_belongs_to_many`. Both use a join table but `has_or_belongs_to_many` does not have a model and is very limited in its actual usefulness. When naming join tables the lazy conventions is to just use an amalgamation of a & b - `CircleUser` but do use a better name if you can think of one that fits the domain.

```
class Circle
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

# rails g model membership user:belongs_to circle:belongs_to
class Membership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :circle
end

class User
  has_many :created_circles, 
    class_name: 'Circle',
    foreign_key: :creator_id
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :circles, through: :memberships
end
```

One thing to bear in mind is that each association MUST have a unique name. If we didn't go through that previous step and wrote:

```
class User
  has_many :circles
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :circles, through: :memberships
end
```

The latter association would just clobber the previous association.

Comment: This is exactly what I need and is well explained! A followup question, when I create a circle like "user1.created_circles.build", the circle doesn't exist in the circles table. "Circle.first" is nil. However user1.created_circles shows that I have this circle. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes. `build` is actually just an alias for `new`. If you want to save the record as well in one call you want `create`.

Comment: In the migration, when you’re changing the `id`, shouldn’t it be `creator_id`?

Comment: @hashrocket yes it should - well spotted